# Can OIDC and SAML work together with keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have applications that support sso integration by using SAML, also I want to adopt OIDC for sso with new applications, question is can I use keycloak to support both SAML and OIDC clients at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, one Keycloak's realm can have multiple clients configured and these clients can use different protocols - SAML and OIDC.